# How can I update filed value from a select with inner join?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-update

I am trying to update a field value in a mysql database using a select query with inner join

I currently get

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS cc WHERE cc.account_id = na.account_id' at line 5

```
UPDATE accounts AS na
SET na.pdm_id = (
SELECT cp.person_id FROM `temp_accounts` AS ta INNER JOIN call_managment_system.accounts AS a ON ta.company_code = a.company_code
INNER JOIN contact_personal AS cp ON cp.name = ta.FSM AND contact_link = 'PDM' 
) 
WHERE a.account_id = na.account_id
```

How can I fix this query to work? I want to update the field called pdm_id to set it equal to cp.person_id

Thanks

Comment: you deleted `AS cc` right? can't find it in your code.

Comment: Where is your `AS ac`?

Comment: can you please explain how `account` is related on the other tables?

Comment: Sorry I just updated my post I have removed cc yes and replaces ac with a.

Comment: So in the table temp_accounts it has company_code column with that I am able to like to the accounts table. then from there I am able to link to contact_personal via FSM field that is located in the temp_accounts field..  I am not sure if I am explaining this clearly.

Comment: I think the problem is that your where clause is outside your subquery instead of inside.

Comment: I tried that but that did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE  accounts na
INNER JOIN call_managment_system.accounts a
ON      a.account_id = na.account_id
INNER JOIN temp_accounts ta 
ON     ta.company_code = a.company_code
INNER JOIN contact_personal cp 
ON cp.name = ta.FSM        
SET     na.pdm_id = cp.person_id
WHERE   contact_link = 'PDM'
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. your query had the correct answer however, I have updated it with a small change. I don't think I was very clear in my post so it lead to some confusion but thanks to you I am able to preform the update :)